# How do I turn off the Minecraft 1.7.2 Super Secret Settings?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How do I turn off the Minecraft 1.7.2 super secret settings? I tried <kbd>F3</kbd> and <kbd>F4</kbd>, hitting <kbd>Esc</kbd> repeatedly, all things mentioned on blogs – nothing is working.

Comment: You don't happen to have a Fn key to go with your F4 key to make it activate properly, do you? I can confirm that pressing F4 *should* put everything back to normal.

Answer (score 19):

Save, quit, and restart. The screen will be back to normal.

Comment: F4 works without needing to do that, as per SynSlash80's answer

Comment: if he is running as a host it would be problem for client steeves

Answer (score 19):

Pressing <kbd>F4</kbd> (or maybe <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>, depending on your keyboard) will reset the shader to default without having to check manually in the <kbd>F3</kbd> screen, and without needing to reload the world.

Comment: While I *can* confirm that this does, indeed, work, we're not very big on the whole self-promotion thing around here (as I think you can probably understand). But other than that, I never knew about the F4 thing, so that's good to know :)

Answer (score 12):

Pressing F3 will show you the shader that is used. Keep this debug information on when going through the Super Secret Settings to see what they're called and when they are turned off (there will not be any information about the shader when it's off).

Answer (score 2):

You can click the super secret settings over and over to cycle through them randomly – one will be normal.

Answer (score 1):

Just keep spam clicking the super secret setting.  It would eventually go back to the normal setting.

Comment: Spam clicking won't garuntee that you will get back to the normal setting.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite old but this hasn't been mentioned so why not? For the future viewers of older posts in need of information:

I noticed that when I hit F5 and cycled through back to the FPS view, it had reset the shaders. This might have just been on one of the sub-versions but it was really useful to know when they still had them.