# The game displays messy colors and pixels movements

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

[image: Minecraft single player with default texturepack]

It looks a bit like the game Borderlands, and it's the same single player as multiplayer. When I use the Sphax PureBDCraft texture pack it also has a small square in the middle as a cursor which looks like it's giving me x-ray. I have no mods installed or anything and i've looked everywhere please help!!

Comment: Now that i see the screenshot it looks normal but while playing it looks like borderlands (if you don't know the game google it you'll find it)

Comment: how in any way does that look like borderlands

Comment: yeah in the game itself it did ook like it but not on the screenshot, but now it's like changing colors of the sky and stuff?! could it be something to do with the 'super secret settings' button? because i kinda spammed that button because of the sounds..

Comment: Bah cant edit my comment. Anyway, the issue looks like your graphics drivers kind of blew up and inverted the colors or something, if this an HD texture pack you might want to try using a patcher instead of manually installing it the vanilla way.

Comment: Yes, super secret settings switches between different shaders. See [http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Shaders](the shaders page) for more details.

Comment: OKE lol it does have to do with that.. i think that settings button is like a trolling thing because i clicked it and returned to the game a couple of times and now everything seems to be normal

Comment: Just post an answer stating how you solved your own question so others might be helped out by this in the future.

Comment: [Related question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/139370/42984)

Comment: Did you try uploading a second screenshot?  The two that are shown are the same.

Answer (score 7):

You have switched on the "wobble" experimental shader by clicking the Super Secret Settings button.

The "Wobble" shader:

> Colors cycle through the hue range constantly. All displayed pixels move up and down via a sine calculation. It should be noted that this only affects the screen plane and not the vertices being displayed by it, as observing the very edge of the screen reveals the pixels being moved.

[image]

Shaders can disabled by pressing the <kbd>F4</kbd> key or restarting you Minecraft client.

[Source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Shaders)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you have clicked the super secret options which uses experimental shaders

Go in and cycle through these until you get back to vanilla

[image: Settings]

Answer (score -1):

Vanilla [Shaders](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Shaders) were added in 1.7, and you are currently in the "Wobble shader."
To disable this, press <kbd>F4</kbd>.