# MineCraft: I'm currently using 1.8.4 and I cant turn of super secret settings

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've tried F4, restarting the game, loading the world again, and also clicking on the super secret settings a couple of time but I am always going in a loop.
Basicaly nothing works, please help me..

(I have looked at questions close to this, and I have ready the answers, and it will doesn't help me, as I explained what I did. But still not working, and it is stille the same).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I turn off the Minecraft 1.7.2 Super Secret Settings?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/139370/how-do-i-turn-off-the-minecraft-1-7-2-super-secret-settings)

Comment: Not really, I have read every comment and answers, and till doesn't help me at all :L

Comment: Are you sure that you effect you are seeing is Super Secret Settings and not something else like 3D Anaglyph? Could you post a screenshot of what you are seeing?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, thanks alot. It was the 3D anaglyph. My bad, thought it were that you see 3D if you drop items :s

Comment: @Elderite colorfusion has added the answer you confirmed below. Remember to accept it by clicking the checkmark below the vote-count, otherwise the question will remain in the unanswered column. Thanks!

Comment: No @Elderite, what I'm saying is that although you yourself have fixed your problem, the question is still marked as unanswered. To fix that, you will need to click the checkmark below the vote-count on his below answer.

Comment: @Hyperum Ok, sorry. I believe I've done it now :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Super Secret Settings` do not persist game reloads, and should reset when <kbd>F4</kbd> is pressed.

As diagnosed in the comments, the problem here is that you have `3D Anaglyph` turned on. You can turn this off from `Video Settings...`, and the effect should disappear.