# The shaders included in "Super Secret Settings" won't turn off!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My super secret setting shader won't turn off! I've tried restarting it, spam clicking the "super secret settings button" and pressing f4. All of the blocks still have a red shadow to it!

Comment: repeated question [link](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/139370/how-do-i-turn-off-the-minecraft-1-7-2-super-secret-settings)

Comment: The asker seems to have tried everythin at least from the top answers. Have all the other answers been unhelpful as well?

Comment: @DJPirtu, A certain user deleted information that was _very_ important. That was the problem.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of this ominous red shadow you are seeing?